# Is there a way for a global variable declared in index.html be used in angular2 components?

Tags: angular

index.html

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var value = '1234';
</script>
```

How do I use the above value in one of the angular 2 components?

Comment: you can access this variable directly like value in angular 2. But make sure you have diclared on top all js files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assign it to `window`

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.myValue = '1234';
</script>
```

then you can read it from everywhere

```
class MyComponent {
  constructor() {
    console.log(window['myValue']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as Gunter said or you could also use a service, which is what I do. Keeps everything more organized.

main.service.ts/

```
 @Injectable()
 export class MainService {
    private myVar= "test";
    getMyVar(){return this.myVar};
 }
```

home.component.ts/

```
  import { MainService } from './main.service';

   @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    providers:[MainService]
 })

 export class AppComponent {
   constructor(private main:MainService){}
   var fromMainVar = this.main.getMyVar;
 }
```